# Set value of a variable in in useEffect from reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to setValue of a variable in useEffect Function, the value i want to set is updated in reducers and i am accessing it in my component by using useSelector but it is not working.
This is my code

```
const{settings} = useSelector(({Account}) => Account);


 useEffect(() => {
    if(settings) {
      Init();
    }
    dispatch(getEmailSettingsAction());
  }, [dispatch, settings]);
```

the settings is initially null in reducer, i want to call the init function when reducer updates it value after `getEmailSettingsAction` is dispatched. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getEmailSettingsAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(settings) {
      Init();
    }
  }, [settings]);
```

This should work. Unless you are getting correct value of settings from useSelector.